# ./gradlew build fails with TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My project is working fine, however when I try the .gradlew build from terminal it ends up with a fail with this error. Im not sure I get it to be honest, any help in this?

```
Unexpected failure during lint analysis of DatabaseHandler.java (this 
is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on) TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType(TypeSystem.java:180)
->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:238)
->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:261)
->LookupEnvironment.createParameterizedType(LookupEnvironment.java:949)


Unexpected failure during lint analysis of DatabaseHandler.java (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on) TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType(TypeSystem.java:180)
    ->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:238)
    ->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:261)
    ->LookupEnvironment.createParameterizedType(LookupEnvironment.java:949)
```

Comment: I downgraded gradle and now its working fine.. what do you know..

Comment: From which to which version did you downgrade what exactly? Gradle itself or the com.android.tools.build:gradle plugin or the android-sdk buildtools referenced by app/build.gradle?

Comment: always run with sudo ./gradlew or with latest gradle with full path to gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downgrading gradle was the solution but usually sudo ./gradle would work fine